# How to convert Midi Time Code to actual time using CoreMidi

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, ios, midi

I'm trying to figure out how to read midi time code from a host.

The Midi SysEx has a byte format like this: 
|f0|7f|channel|01|subID|hours|minutes|secs|frame|f7|

When I receive midi message I get this. usually 10-11 bytes:
f0 00 00 66 05 00 11 00 03 f7
f0 00 00 66 05 00 11 01 02 f7
f0 00 00 66 05 00 11 01 05 f7
etc.

How do I convert this into a running format like this 0m:00s.000ms using CoreMidi?
I know how to program static variables just need to know how to convert from midi time to actual time. Thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIDI_timecode and http://web.media.mit.edu/~meyers/mcgill/multimedia/senior_project/MTC.html

Comment: i found a [wayback-machine version](http://web.archive.org/web/20110629053759/http://web.media.mit.edu/~meyers/mcgill/multimedia/senior_project/MTC.html) of secondary link similar to @nik-reiman answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are technically asking how to convert SMPTE to HMS. You should check out the following links:

- http://home.roadrunner.com/~jgglatt/tech/mtc.htm
- http://web.media.mit.edu/~meyers/mcgill/multimedia/senior_project/MTC.html (thx @sehe)

Comment: Really? SMTPE is MTC? I should've known that. +1 I'll need this answer at some point in the future.